# Updating user via J4 REST API resets password

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-4, restful-api

In our organization we use Salesforce as the authoritative source of info about our users, so it makes sense for us to use that info when creating the associated users in our new Joomla site.

I have written code in Salesforce that calls the Joomla 4 API and creates these Joomla users if they don’t already exist, and then it updates their Joomla group memberships.

This code gets called any time we make changes in Salesforce that would impact the user's group membership rights, so if the user already exists, it just updates group memberships.

All this works great except for one problem:

Whenever I update a user using a PATCH API call, it somehow changes or invalidates the password, so I can no longer login as that user.  For some reason, Joomla changes the password even though in my PATCH call, I don’t include the password or password2 fields.  For example:

https://zzzzz.com/api/index.php/v1/users/957 (PATCH)

{"groups":{"14":14,"24":24,"9":9,"2":2,"1":1}}

Can you think of any way to avoid having Joomla change or invalidate the password on a PATCH call?

Note that this behavior also happens if I call the API using Postman, so this is not a Salesforce issue.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug. You should report it to the developers.

Comment: Good idea.  Submitted: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/41681